# Writing functions in Postgres that returns strings with dots in reverse like java namespaces

Tags: postgresql, functions

Looking for a Postgres 9.6 function that reverse sorts a string the same way that java namespaced packages do.  Preferable if this is just PGSQL, I know that this is simple in the V8 engine or Python.

I.e. if I have the string `foo.bar.baz.example.com`, I want the string `com.example.baz.bar.foo`.  My very naive attempts like running a 
`REVERSE` on the string didn't work.

I'm thinking I would need to explode on the periods, (can you explode in Postgres?), start a cursor, loop over the set, insert the last item from the set, shift that item off the set, and continue until the set is empty.

But I don't know how to do any of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of array functions:

```
select string_agg(x, '.' order by idx desc)
from unnest(string_to_array('foo.bar.baz.example.com','.')) with ordinality as t(x, idx);
```

you can put this into a function if you want:

```
create function reverse_elements(p_words text)
  returns text
as
$$
  select string_agg(x, '.' order by idx desc)
  from unnest(string_to_array(p_words,'.')) with ordinality as t(x, idx);
$$
language sql;
```

Comment: Lifesaver.  I tried this:

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION REVERSE_SORT_DOTS(unordered_string TEXT) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
    BEGIN
     DECLARE new_string TEXT DEFAULT '';
    
     arr varchar[] := SELECT string_to_array(REVERSE(unordered_string), '.');
     FOREACH element IN ARRAY arr
      new_string := CONCAT(element, '.', new_string);
     LOOP
     END LOOP;
      
      RETURN new_string;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

But it didn't work.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: thanks, good point. I changed it

Answer (score 1):

## Using [`plperl`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl.html)

String modification is *really* slow when you're using `string_agg`, and `unnest` and `ordinality`. You'll find plperl to be over twice as fast as the sql method.

```
CREATE FUNCTION reverse_perl(p_words text)
  RETURNS text
AS
$$
  return join ".", reverse split /\./, $_[0];
$$
LANGUAGE plperl
STRICT
IMMUTABLE;
```

Benchmark,

```
test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT reverse_perl( array_to_string(ARRAY[x,x,x,x], '.') ) FROM generate_series(1,100) AS gs(x);
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Function Scan on generate_series gs  (cost=0.00..262.50 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.104..1.477 rows=100 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.054 ms
 Execution time: 1.519 ms
(3 rows)

Time: 2.030 ms
test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT reverse_elements( array_to_string(ARRAY[x,x,x,x], '.') ) FROM generate_series(1,100) AS gs(x);
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Function Scan on generate_series gs  (cost=0.00..262.50 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.236..4.161 rows=100 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.147 ms
 Execution time: 4.208 ms
(3 rows)

Time: 4.770 ms
```

Granted, this is a pretty simple query and it probably doesn't matter for most reasonable use cases.

Comment: Very helpful.  I tried the PGSQL method and it was slower than doing the same thing natively (Python), which I assumed was because postgres probably doesn't optimize arrays as much as Python.

Comment: @user3112092 plpython, because if the failures of python is not trusted in PostgreSQL. I grab plv8 or plperl depending on the task. Plperl is usually faster with string manipulation.